# Adding request params to observer redirect

Tags: event-observer, controllers

I have an observer catching `sales_quote_add_item` to do various things when adding to cart.

One of those things is to redirect to my own controller if a products needs further customization, deferring add to cart and allowing the user to add from a customization page.

I would like to pass my form params from the first page through the redirect to the customization page; however, these params will be fairly extensive and I don't really want to pollute my URL so I'd like to just pass them as params on the request.

Currently:

```
class My_Module_Model_Observer
{
    // From product page, user can add to cart or "customize"
    // if they customize, we need to catch params and forward to customize controller
    public function myEventMethod($o)
    {
        // custom form fields from product page
        $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();

        if (isset($params['needs_customize'])) {
            // redirect to '/customize'
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customize'));
            // This will pass params along, but they will be appended to URL, which I want to avoid.
            // Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customize'), $params);
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        // .... other code that handles some add to cart logic. If customized, they never get here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing a redirect you cannot set the params in the request object.
I mean, you can but it's useless. Once the redirect is done, the request object is re-populated.
You have to send your values through `$_GET` or you can store them in the session and in your `customize` action read them from the session and remove them.

Comment: I suppose sessions it is. Are there events that I could hook into to modify the request object when it gets re-populated, or would that require some bold rewrites?

Comment: You can use `controller_action_predispatch_{action_name_here}`.  So if your page is `module/controller/action` the event will be `controller_action_predispatch_module_controller_action`.